# Best way to handle many-to-many relations with Codeigniter and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, many-to-many

I really couldn't find anything useful. I'm making my own Admin panel with Codeigniter and MySQL, and everything is done, except for the many-to-many relations.

The main table is Product table. I have 5 many to many relations (Categories, Materials, Colors, Tags, Cities). There are 5 tables for each of them with these columns (ID, and name of category/tag/city...) and of course there are tables between that has both IDs of the Product and the other table.

As first, I want to list all the products in one table, and in the columns I want to have column for categories, materials, tags, etc. and in the corresponding to cell, all the items to be listed with comma...

Here is how one row should look like.

| ID | Name | Description | Category 1, Category 2, ... | Material 1, ... | Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4, ... |

I hope you understood me. And next, hopefully, the Add function seems easy, but the Update function should be really tricky I guess, so any help for there is also appreciated, hot to solve it to be as fast as it can.
I guess that first I should check for all the selected items to check if there is any new entry that is not in the linking table, and then to check if any of the unselected is in the linking table to delete it. 
How to do this to be most optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly a codeigniter thing, more of a thing with SQL.

Managing the display is the simple part. You can join all the related tables and `GROUP BY` your `product_id` so your result set only displays a single product once. Then you can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT` function of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to group the related table fileds per row.

The performance of this really depends on the application and its usage. For example, with an app we have, it is quicker and more responsive to run multiple queries per row returned by the `product_id` to get the other information, rather than running one single query to get all information in one hit. So, you have to test it out.

With the update, yes, it can be messy. One way is to drop all existing by `product_id` and then add all the submitted ones. Another is to check the existing ones against the submitted ones and only add the new ones and remove the ones that don't match. I hope that makes sense to you :)

Comment: Can you show me some example code? I (think I) know how to find all the categories, materials, cities, tags, etc. for one single Product. I will search all of the tables for the corresponding product ID, and I guess that's it. 5 many to many relations, 5 different queries and I think it can't be solve simpler.

But about listing all the table with products (display list of 1000 products) and in each row to be all the tags, all the cities, all the categories...? Can you show me example how to use what you have told me?

Comment: I have these tables:
Products, Tags, Prod_Tags, Cities, Prod_City, Material, Prod_Mat.

This is enough, if you show me for two of them, I will do the rest. In every table there is ID field and Name field.

Comment: May be you should try to implement something based on the suggested solution (or any other way) and come back to stackoverflow with specific problems you face.

Comment: Actually this was easy, I solved the Select part of the CRUD with GROUP_CONCAT() and GROUP BY. I have learned about them at faculty, but no one understood them obviously until we use them in some real project :)
The Add part should not be big deal.
The Update part I will listen your advice too, I will delete the existing, and add the new ones, it's less complex, and I will have less code too.

Comment: I just reviewed the generated results, and I have duplicates for the cities and materials (I used only those 2 in the select) according to the number of concatenated rows as I can see... So now I need help to filter them somehow to remove the duplicates

SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name_city) as cities, GROUP_CONCAT(m.name_mat) as materials
FROM products as p, 
     pr_city as pc, cities as c,
     pr_mat as pm, materials as m
WHERE p.id = pc.id_pr AND pc.id_city = c.id
AND p.id = pm.id_pr AND pm.id_mat = m.id
GROUP BY p.id

Comment: What if you convert this to be a series of `LEFT JOIN`ed tables? SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name_city) AS cities, GROUP_CONCAT(m.name_mat) AS materials
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN pr_city pc ON p.id = pc.id_pr
LEFT JOIN cities c ON pc.id_city = c.id
LEFT JOIN pr_mat pm ON p.id = pm.id_pr
LEFT JOIN materials m ON pm.id_mat = m.id
WHERE GROUP BY p.id

Comment: I solved it, I added DISTINCT in GROUP_CONCAT() so now I have GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name_city)... and it works. I hope this is the right way to do that and get the correct results in every case? At least it works for couple of test works in the database...

Comment: We posted at the same time. Which way should be faster? With LEFT JOIN or my way which I think is with Inner join? Anyway I tested your query, WHERE was giving error, without where it works, but doesn't solve the problem, there are still duplicates with your.

Comment: Yea - the query should not have WHERE - anyway, use whatever works for you, but understand why it works, so you know how to handle it next time.

Comment: And one more question. If there are not entries in the linking table (for example there are not materials), the result is not displayed. How do I filter this so the product will be displayed with that column empty?

Comment: @MarkC That's when a `LEFT JOIN` is helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins it will only join records that matchs up with the records on the tables specified on the left.